# How can i use the gotoAndStop function if my stage is a sprite in actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, flash-cs5, tile, stage

so i am working on a game that is very siilar to tony.pa's tile-based tutorials
I have this function.

```
function isTeleporter (xt:int, yt:int):Boolean 
    {
        if(currentMap[yt][xt] == 105)
        {
            return true;
        }else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In my everyframe function i have this

```
if(isTeleporter(hero.xtile, hero.ytile))
           {
               myParent.gotoAndStop(2);
           }
```

It gives this error
    1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite.

I believe it is because to generate the game in the first frame i have this

```
import TBGEngine;
//call new tbg with Sprite as parameter, tbg will place all visible objects inside this sprite
var mygame:TBGEngine = new TBGEngine(this);
```

I want to be able to switch frames and have a new level that on the new frame or a credit screen or an animation or something, but currently i have no idea how to do so.
Any help is greatly appreciated! Im a sixteen year old highschool student in a small town with no computer science program at my school, so im pretty much on my own.

Comment: Use MovieClip instead of Sprite. Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `gotoAndStop()` on Sprite because Sprite does not have this method - it is not intended to be used with animations. Imagine Sprite as a simple one-framed Movieclip. Whenever you want to use animations inside of a DisplayObjectContainer you *MUST* use MovieClip. Same if you are subclassing Sprite - your subclass will not be able to go to any frame.

Comment: How can I make it so that i can change frames? Is there a way to make this sprite a movie clip?

Comment: I don't know where you need to change it but looking at your code I would say you change it from the TBGEngine's constructor and find every reference to that variable.

Comment: I just made it into a movieclip, but it is now kicking up an error about it referencing a static type TBGEngine. What should i do?

Comment: I don't know what you should do because I don't know how those classes work. Now that you know what the problem is, I guess you can find a solution to it. We don't know what is "myParent" and what you pass to TBGEngine constructor, neither how TBGengine works.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks so much for the help! I do have a question though. If i switch frames and create a new level, does flash auto garbage collect the old frame? Im worried about lag over time and if music from the old frame will continue to play on top of music on the new frame?

Comment: I would say it gets garbage collected unless you have the instance on the other frame. The music is different case because you can select the Sync options in the IDE. I assume if you put it as "stream" , it will stop (I am not sure in that but seems logical). You can also use something like SoundMixer.stopAll();